# Accessing the 'Name' property of an object in C#

Tags: c#, object

I am learning C# (I'm new to it) and am building a small Airport application. I want to be able to get the names of the planes that are in the airport rather than simply knowing that the List contains various `Airport.Plane` objects. My code at the moment is:

Airport.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Airport
{
    public class Airport
    {
        public List<object> planes;

        public Airport()
        {
            planes = new List<object>();
        }

        public List<object> Land(object plane)
        {
            planes.Add(plane);
            Console.WriteLine("Currently in the airport:");
            planes.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            return planes;
        }

        public List<object> TakeOff(object plane)
        {
            planes.Remove(plane);
            Console.WriteLine("Currently in the airport:");
            planes.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            return planes;
        }

        public int GetPlaneCount()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(planes.Count);
            return planes.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Plane.cs:

```
using System;
namespace Airport
{
    public class Plane
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Plane(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;

namespace Airport
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Airport airport = new Airport();
            Plane plane = new Plane("Private Jet");
            airport.Land(plane);
            airport.TakeOff(plane);
            airport.GetPlaneCount();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to access the name of the Plane in the airport by `Console.Log(plane.Name);` but I get the following error: 
"'object' does not contain a definition for Name". Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Make your lists `List<Plane>` rather than `List<object>`...?

Comment: The code you are showing us doesn't contain `Console.Log(plane.Name);` anywhere.  Please show us *all relevant code* so we can see if you've made a mistake elsewhere.  Don't assume where the mistake lies; let us help you to determine that by looking at all of your code.

Comment: Try not to use `object` when you can use a more specific class. So your lists would be better off as `List<Plane>` and your method signatures should take a `Plane` rather than `object` as parameters

Comment: You can also override ToString in your Plane class to return the Name.

Comment: instead of passing and return object, make it a plane

Comment: WHAT would be very useful interms of ppl helping you, is seeing how you are consuming everything... aka main method.

Comment: Thanks @Seabizkit, I have updated the code with the Main method - although I'm still a little unsure with what to use this for

Comment: @jordantomiko see answer hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

some pseudo code to help you understand

```
public class Airport
{
    public string AirportName { get; set;}

    public List<Plane> planes;

    public Airport(string airportName)
    {
        AirportName = airportName;
        planes = new List<Plane>();
    }

    public List<Plane> Land(Plane plane)
    {
        planes.Add(plane);
        return planes;
    }

    public List<Plane> TakeOff(Plane plane)
    {
        planes.Remove(plane);
        return planes;
    }

    public int GetPlaneCount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(planes.Count);
        return planes.Count;
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    var capeTownAirport = new Airport("Cape Town")

    var planeA = new Plane("facy plane");
    var planeB = new Plane("Another facy plane");

    var currentPlans = capeTownAirport.Land(planeA);            

    var currentPlans2 = capeTownAirport.Land(planeA);

    foreach(var plane in currentPlans2)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(plane.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Seabizkit that is really helpful. If you don't mind, could I also ask a question about return values in C# - is there any point to returning the planes in the Land and TakeOff methods? Or could I declare `void`? I am unsure of C# best practices?

Comment: @jordantomiko The only relevant "best practice" I can think of there is to only write code you need. So, if you need to use the plane, then return the plane, and do whatever you need to do with it. If you don't need it, then don't return it, and declare void instead.

Comment: @jordantomiko yes, your starting to get it,... make the add and remove void, void means they dont return anything. then create a new method, like`List<Planes> GetPlanes()', which then actually just returns the list you have been adding and removing from.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, [C# is for the most part a statically typed programming language](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/10/15/is-c-a-strongly-typed-or-a-weakly-typed-language/), so if you declare something as object you will only see object's properties, fields and methods. You can easily fix this by casting your object to Plane, but sticking to a known type is always the best way to go.

```
var plane = new Plane("My plane");

object myObject = plane;
// Console.WriteLine(myObject.Name); // Compiler complains here - object doesn't have Name property or field defined

Console.WriteLine((Plane)myObject); // Compiler is happy here, but you should never do it like that!
```

As it was said in the comments to your question, use strongly typed lists (List< Plane > instead of List< object >) and it will work fine.